# How to catch Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: perl, x11, gtk3

There are many similar questions about programs crashing, but I don't see any quite like what I'm asking...

When I use `xkill` to kill my application, I get the following message on stderr:

```
(foo.pl:32471): Gdk-WARNING **: foo.pl: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.
```

What I'd like to do (if possible) is catch that event and do some cleanup (save prefs, etc) before exiting.

Setup:

- Linux
- Perl 5.16
- Gtk3 3.8.8

**Edit:**

Sample source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Gtk3 -init;
my $win = Gtk3::Window->new;
$win->signal_connect('delete-event' => sub { cleanup('delete-event') } );
$win->signal_connect('destroy' => sub { cleanup('destroy') } );
$win->signal_connect('destroy-event' => sub { cleanup('destroy-event') } );
$win->signal_connect('unmap-event' => sub { cleanup('unmap-event') } );
$win->signal_connect('unmap' => sub { cleanup('unmap') } );
$win->show_all;
Gtk3->main;

sub cleanup {
    my $event = shift;
    print "Doing cleanup due to signal '$event'\n";
}
```

When using `xkill` on this app, the print statement isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that `foo.pl` involves a GUI of sorts.

As for `xkill`, from its man page on my system

> Xkill is a utility for forcing the X server to close connections to clients.  This program is very dangerous, [...]

In other words, it "pulls the carpet out" from under your application, closing connection to it.  You can look inside of it for kinds of events it receives as this happens, which depends on how it's written. Then you can  set up a callback for it.

I think that we'd more detail to comment on that.

Comment: Added sample code which connects several signals, none of which catch this event... perhaps I'm just not connecting the correct one, or perhaps there's a different approach.

Comment: @TheAmigo  I see -- thank you.  Yes, none of these events are for server closing the connection ... I'm looking at docs, can't remember

Comment: @TheAmigo  The signal/event need be at quite high level (I'm not sure that the window itself will get a chance).  I looked at [Glib exceptions](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Glib.html#EXCEPTIONS) for example (but that's just a guess).  Altogether I came up empty for now, will be able to look at it more later.

Comment: Thanks for checking... I've been poking around in a couple more directions, but haven't turned up anything useful or promising yet.